# Is it possible to go directly to the business information page in the Apple Maps app on iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit, openurl, apple-maps

I am writing an app that includes information for various venues. I'd like to provide the user with the ability to open the location information screen from the Apple Maps app. I know how to have the app open an MKMapItem with code like the following:

```
- (void) showMoreInfoFor:(MKPlacemark*) destination {
    MKLocalSearchRequest* searchRequest = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = self.venue.name;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(destination.coordinate, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    searchRequest.region = region;
    MKLocalSearch* search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:searchRequest];
    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if ([response.mapItems count] > 0) {
            [[response.mapItems objectAtIndex:0] openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

(I've also tried skipping the local search, just creating a new MKMapItem directly with the `destination` placemark, with exactly the same results.)

However, this takes the user to a screen that looks like:

[image: Map screen with pin for placemark]

I'd prefer that the user be taken to the following screen directly, instead of requiring the user to tap on the disclosure indicator on the place mark.

[image: Map business information screen]

I've also tried using an Apple maps link (as per the [Apple URL Scheme Reference for Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)) like this:

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?sll=%f,%f&q=%@", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude, [self.venue.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

but this takes the user to a screen similar to the first one above, except that in many cases it shows a pin that's nowhere near the lat/lon specified in the URL (in completely different cities, for example). It also doesn't drill in to the location information screen.

Is it possible to navigate from an iOS app into the Apple Maps app, going directly to the business/location information screen as seen in the second screenshot above?

Comment: here is a suggestion. Official docs indicates that these links can go both to safari and apple maps. Try to navigate via safari and check out the link (on the bussiness page) that can give you a hint.